# xampp mysql is not working (win 10)

Tags: mysql, xampp

I've installed xampp on win10. Everything work wen I run Apache server. When I start Mysql server I get this error message

```
20:40:55  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
20:40:55  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
20:40:55  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
20:40:55  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
20:40:55  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
20:40:55  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
20:40:55  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

I've already installed Mysql 8.0 on my pc before installing xampp.
I've tried to chang the port number in my.ini file from the config button of xampp. But in the log files I got always the same 3306 port

```
2019-04-28 17:07:35 37872 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2019-04-28 17:07:35 37872 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Someone know how I can solve this problem? I already tried all the solution alredy posted for similar question and nothing worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Is your MySql 8 already running? If so then stop MySql 8 and try running MySql from XAMPP again. This should fix your issue.

Comment: thanx now working!!